# Folder "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" Is Missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pthreads

I'm trying to add `pthread` library to Visual Studio 2017 (I'm using Windows 10 OS). I'm using the following [guide](https://web.cs.du.edu/%7Esturtevant/w13-sys/InstallingpthreadsforVisualStudio.pdf) from another post tat I saw, but I can't find the "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" folder in "C:\Program Files x86". I have Visual Studio 2017 and It's working. I've checked and I've installed the Visual Studio C++. What else should I install? Is there any other way to include `pthread` library by just adding it to the project and including the path to the library in the linker or something similar?

Thank you

Comment: VS2017 is Visual Studio 15.0

Comment: @jkb Thank you for your comment. I have only the folder "Microsoft Visual Studio" without any number after it, and I can't find the path which are specified in the guide (I also looked at other guides and they use the same paths as the one I've mentioned in the post does). I don't understand what's missing

Comment: Your edited post is a completely new question and should be asked as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since visual studio 2017 visual studio is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\<version>\<edition>` by default e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community`. There are other changes to the internal layout of files within the visual studio directory too. Your guide seems to only provide libraries for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, these won't work in 2017, you should try to find an updated guide (or just use `std::thread` instead of `pthread`s).

Installing these files inside the visual studio directory isn't the right approach anyway, install them to a directory of your choice and update your project settings to point to that directory. The lazy approach in the guide is likely to cause problems in the long run.

Comment: @AlanBritles Thank you for your comment. I'm trying to follow your advice, and since I'm having trouble installing `pthread` I'm trying to "translate" the C code into C++ so I can use `<thread>` instead (I have only few lines). Unfortunately, when I changed the code, some weird errors occurred (as I mentioned in my edited post). Perhaps you have any idea what could go wrong? Thank you once again